# Iterating products in shopify product-loop.liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, product

I have a problem with displaying a collection of products with a help of snippet product-loop.liquid in Shopify. The code is basically the following.

```
{% capture collection_handle %}{{ product-loop | handleize }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture url %}{% if collection_handle != "" %}/collections/{{ product-loop }}{{ product.url }}{% else %}{{ product.url }}{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
<div class="product span3 {% if template == 'collection' %}adaptive-grid{% endif %}">



</div>

{% unless template contains 'collection' %}
{% cycle 'clear-product-loop': '', '', '', '<div style="clear:both;"></div>' %}
{% endunless %}
```

The result is one row is 2 items or 3 items or 4 items (depending on screen resolution) and the next row is always 1 item and this pattern is repeating all the time. What is wrong?

EDIT: Some related CSS

```
.row { margin: 0 0 30px 0; }
.span1, .span2, .span3, .span4, .span5, .span6, .span7, .span8, .span9, .span10, .span11, .span12 { display: block; float: left; margin: 0 15px; }
.inner-left { margin-left: 0px !important; }
.inner-right { margin-right: 0px !important; }  


.span1 { width: 53px; }
.span2 { width: 136px; }
.span3 { width: 219px; }
.span4 { width: 302px; }

.span3.adaptive-grid {width: 219px;}
.span3.adaptive-grid:nth-child(6n+7) {clear: none;}
.span3.adaptive-grid:nth-child(4n+5) {clear: both;}
```

Comment: What are `product-loop` and `clear-product-loop`? And how many products? I don't see a loop to process products here.

Comment: There are about 20 products so no problems with quantity. product-loop and clear-product-loop I think these are standard things from Shopify, sorry if I am wrong

Comment: Umm no, they must have come with the theme. Can you post the output of `{{ product-loop }}` and you're using `cycle` syntax wrongly.

Comment: From console I get: ReferenceError: product is not defined. And what is wrong with cycle?

Comment: I was asking for `{{ product-loop }}` in liquid output, not javascript console. `cycle` is to be used inside a `for` loop and the syntax is `{% cycle 'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' ... %}` . There is no `for` loop in your code and `'clear-product-loop': ''` is the wrong syntax.

Comment: I can remove last three lines, that doesn't change anything

Comment: I think it is ruled by css, will add it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved my problem by removing lines like

```
.span3.adaptive-grid:nth-child(6n+7) {clear: none;}
.span3.adaptive-grid:nth-child(4n+5) {clear: both;}
```

from Shopify styles file (Minimal theme). Now the grid of products is displayed ok for different resolutions without breaking the lines.